# What runs .NET Framework WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, model-view-controller

I made a "Mistake" jumping to .NETCore, MVC5 WebApi...
Eventually I realized I have a 3rd party library that is incompatible with NetCore.
therefore, after some extensive effort, i neglected Core, and ported back to .Net45.

Everything is well, but my WebApi project:
When Porting my WebApi i had to Remove Kestrel (as it isn't supported in NET45),

Now i faced a dilema, as i removed `class Startup {}`,
i realized i cant "Easly" add `global.asax` to my project, and even when adding it, it doesn't function as i wanted it to.

Naturally, i worked-around, Created a Plain `Net Framework WebApi` project,
instead of my `Net Core WebApi(.net framework)` project.
but it hit me: "I don't know what runs the `global.asax` `HttpApplication`

and let's say I'd still rather use my existing project (or lets say `.Net Console Application`) to listen on `Http` request and act as MVC...
What should i do?

inspecting the `.Net WebApi Template` didn't get me much further, 
and didn't find any resources about it online.

In summary, my question is:
***How can one Run .Net Framework MVC WebApi without using the built in template ?***

Comment: Startup in .NET 4.5 is done via Microsoft.Owin. If you get that dependency back into your application then it will Owin which will run your WebApi

Comment: @CallumLinington Tried adding `[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(DropshopWebApp.Startup))]` to my Startup class file, but it doesn't go... i'll look into OWIN... if you can shed some light, it will be great

Comment: I have a project on GitHub which implements it, I'll make it public later

Comment: when i use .NET451+, is there a built in server implementation?

Comment: @CallumLinington Thanks, after reading about OWIN, I learned a lot. You should post your answer + Your Implementation, so i can accept it. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1122162/Implement-Owin-Pipeline-using-Asp-net-Core